# Carrot2 dcs language

Tags: carrot2

I've installed Carrot2 on a web application (PHP language). Everything works perfectly. Now i want to change the language of my results. I want to change english for french. I search on carrot2 documentation, on the web but i didn't find what i want (this link was usefull but it seems like the dcs folder had change since this post `http://carrot2-users-and-developers-forum.607571.n2.nabble.com/Change-Language-in-DCS-REST-PHP-td639270.html`). Anyway, i pass my paramaters (algo, query, source, etc.) with a simple form (and differents variables) and send them (PHP) to carrot2's method with curl.  I tried different (strange or barbaric) ways to send french language :

```
$language = 'lang_fr'; // or $language = 'FRENCH'
$num = (isset($_GET["maxResult"])) ? $_GET["maxResult"] : "10";
$query = urlencode($_GET["query"]);
$source = "web";
$algorithm = "lingo";
$hierarchy = "max-hierarchy-depth";
$level_hierarchie= $_GET["deep"] ? $_GET["deep"] : "1";

$processor = new Carrot2Processor();
$job = new Carrot2Job();
$job->setSource($source);
$job->setQuery($query);
$job->setAlgorithm($algorithm);
$job->setAttribute("results", $num);
$job->setAttribute($hierarchy, $level_hierarchie);
```

i tried to set language like this in the setAttribute() funtion and of course it doesn't work.

```
$job->setAttribute("language", $language);

try {
    $result = $processor->cluster($job);
} catch (Carrot2Exception $e) {
    echo 'An error occurred during processing: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit(10);
}
```

I Also tried to change the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`(add '`Accept-langugage: fr'`).
I see different responses but only for developpers using java and im using php. Is it possible to pass language choice with the setAttribute() method on PHP? Someone knows a way to do that?

Thank you in advance (i use carrot2-dcs-3.16)

Comment: I found the solution. I have modified the carrot2-dcs.war file in my dcs/war folder. This folder contains all the java and xml files. I modified 'algorithm-lingo-attributes.xml' and 'source-etools-attributes.xml'. I have uncommented the code and replaced 'ENGLISH' with 'FRENCH'. To edit this code i use 7-zip because decompressing and recompressing the war file creates a complete mess. 
It seems to work, do not hesitate to send me comments if this is not the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the eTools meta search engine, you can set the [EToolsDocumentSource.language](http://%09EToolsDocumentSource.language) attribute directly in your calling code:

`$job->setAttribute("EToolsDocumentSource.language", "FRENCH");`

See the attribute documentation linked above for the list of supported languages.

Comment: Thank you very much, so much simpler